# $\int_{\alpha}^{y} (e^{\sigma^2x}-k)e^{\mu x}(2y-x)e^{-\frac{(2y-x)^2}{2t}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have this integral:

> $$\int_{\alpha}^{y} (e^{\sigma^2x}-k)e^{\mu x}(2y-x)e^{-\frac{(2y-x)^2}{2t}}dx$$

It's ok to do separate as $$\int_{\alpha}^{y}(e^{\sigma^2x}-k)e^{\mu x}dx \quad \int_{\alpha}^{y}(2y-x)e^{-\frac{(2y-x)^2}{2t}}dx$$

I compute: $$\int_{\alpha}^{y}(2y-x)e^{-\frac{(2y-x)^2}{2t}}dx = te^{-\frac{y^2}{2t}}- te^{-\frac{(2y-\alpha )^2}{2t}}$$

and $$\int_{\alpha}^{y}(e^{\sigma^2x}-k)e^{\mu x}dx=\frac{e^{y(\sigma ^2 +\mu )}-e^{\alpha (\sigma ^2 +\mu )}}{\sigma ^2 + \mu } + \frac{-ke^{y\mu }+ke^{\alpha \mu} }{\mu}$$

I am not shure if that is ok, if I can separate this, please help me, thank you!

Comment: In general, you cannot split integrals like that. You can only do this when the operation is addition, not multiplication (e.g. $\int (f+g) dx = \int f dx + \int g dx$, but $\int fg dx \neq \int f dx \cdot \int g dx$ - usually). The correct version of this is to use integration by parts: $\int fg dx = f \int g dx - \int f'g dx$

Comment: I thought it wasn't correct, thank you very much! But this two integrals are correct?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire - these are definite integrals. The value of the constant is fixed by the need for them to be $0$ when $y = \alpha$, which they are.